# How to set focus on a particular tab in jface on button click

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

The problem I am facing right now is that I want a particular tab on the `tabbedfolder` to be the active one on click of a button. I have tried the `setFocus()` method on the composite contained in this tab but it is not working how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
tabFolder.setSelection(tabIndex/tabItem)
```

Also, you may want to use

```
tabItem.getControl().setFocus()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `.forceFocus()` could be helpful, too.